# How To Convert Value To Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code part which my friend coded for a project and it uses jQuery library. I have no idea how to put this in Javascript so I can remove jQuery from the project.

```
function generateButtonClicked() {
    disableGenerateButton();
    var t = $(".speed").toArray(),
        e = $(".status").toArray();
    t.reverse(), e.reverse(), doNextBox(t, e)
}

function tripConnecting(t, e, n, a, c, l) {
    $(c).html("Connecting"), tripDestination(n, function () {
        tripMeasurement(t, e, n, a, c, l)
    })
}
```

I used an [online tool](https://the-code-monkey.github.io/JQuery2JS/) to convert this and it gave me the following code but it is not working properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
functiongenerateButtonClicked() {
    disableGenerateButton().vart = (".speed").toArray(), e = (".status").toArray().t.reverse(), e.reverse(), doNextBox(t, e)
}
functiontripConnecting(t, e, n, a, c, l) {
    (c).html("Connecting"), tripDestination(n, function () {
        tripMeasurement(t, e, n, a, c, l)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function generateButtonClicked() {
    disableGenerateButton();
    var t = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("speed")),
        e = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("status"));
    t.reverse(); // You could also add `.reverse` to the above declarations.
    e.reverse();
    doNextBox(t, e);
}

function tripConnecting(t, e, n, a, c, l) {
    c.innerHTML = "Connecting";
    tripDestination(n, function () {
        tripMeasurement(t, e, n, a, c, l);
    });
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for your time for looking into this.

Comment: Oh, wait! I mistakenly put a `;` instead of a `,` in the 3rd line. I'm going to edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Method toArray from jQuery looks like:

```
const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.speed'))
```

Comment: `$(c).html("Connecting")` can be replaced as `el.textContent = "Connecting"` if it's not a collection. If it is just iterate them